# binding a WPF ListBox SelectedItem to a list

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox, selection

I have a listbox that has its SelectionMode property set to Multiple.

Is it possible to bind the SelectedItem property to a List? and not to a single item?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using Samuel's solution for this and it works very well.

http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/02/how-to-databind-to-selecteditems.html

Comment: The answer of Jobi Joy is pretty simple and works fine. Why reinventing the wheel and wasting time by reading that blog article? Beauty is in the simplicity :)

Comment: @Stacked: Probably because jobi's solution involves 2 listboxes, while the OP might want his selecteditems to be represented in the same listbox his sourceitems are.

Comment: @Djerry You don't need to use 2 ListBoxes, I just like the idea of using the ElementName attribute.

Comment: One ListBox binds its ItemsSource to YourCollection. The other binds its ItemsSource to the first's SelectedItems. I am curious how you think this trick could be reduced to a single ListBox.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ListBox.SelectedItems property for this.

```
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems , ElementName=listBox}"/>
```

Comment: The question asks to bind the SelectedItem (I presume they meant SelectedItems) to a List, not to the ItemsSource of another ListBox.